# How to store a variable from a reader outside of a while statement

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have the following while statement:

```
while (reader.Read()) {string bin_type = reader.GetString(0);}
```

Because this is in a while i cannot access this variable after it has been stored. How can I store the value from a reader so that it can be used outside of the while statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use global variable For exp....

```
string bin_type=string.Empty;
while (reader.Read()) {bin_type += reader.GetString(0);}
```

Comment: This value is access after completed while statement.

Comment: ah so if it is defined outside of the while it will retain the value?

Comment: @Richard1996 You do know it will just be the last value read?

Comment: yes it will retain because it's declare outside the while loop scope. you can try it.

Comment: Tested and works, will accept the answer when it allows.

Comment: Should use StringBuilder

Comment: ya many option available for this scenario like StringBuilder, List ect....

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to read in everything available to the reader. Would it make more sense to store the variable outside and append the values?

```
string bin_type = "";
while(reader.Read()) {
    bin_type += reader.GetString(0);
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right this will work.

```
string bin_type;
while (reader.Read()) {
    bin_type = reader.GetString(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I understand you need to store only the last valor. If that's true, all you need to do is to declare your variable outside of `while` loop. Like this:

```
string bin_type;

while(reader.read())
    bin_type = reader.GetString(0);
```

Notice that this is not the best method, since you have to iterate over every single item in your reader in order to get what you want. I would need you to post some more of your code, so I could understand better.

In case you need all the data in your reader, you should use a `List`. Like this:

```
List<string> bin_type = new List<string>();

while(reader.read())
    bin_type.Add(reader.read(0));
```

This way, you can access all the data in the reader after the loop.

You could also consider processing your data **inside** the loop for optimization purposes.